# Can't I change the sound volume with the screen locked?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, audio, volume-control, podcast

When I'm listening to my podcasts, with the screen locked and turned off, isn't there a way to enable change the sound volume (with the physical volume buttons)?

**--update**

I'm on a Motorola Razr D3.

Comment: It really depends on the device. Some that is a standard feature with others it takes a little work.

Answer (score 3):

That most likely depends on what phone and interface you have. On, say, a Galaxy S3 with the stock TouchWiz UI, when music is playing in the Samsung player or in Google Play Music, the volume control is enabled at the lock screen. On some other devices, it may not be possible. May I suggest editing your post to include which phone model you have?

Comment: Included, it's a Motorola Razr D3.

Answer (score 1):

In CM they have a hack (or implementation) so that you can change the volume over the lockscreen by pressing the volume up/down key. Also pressing it multiple times will seek/change the track. Now I had two cellphones Optimus one from LG (GB) and another mobistel clone (running ICS) and the CM rom worked for both of them. Firstly requesting, include the model of your phone here and if possible check for some GB/ICS rom to have this feature by default.

**EDIT**: Is this device the same you have? http://get.cm/?device=solana
In case you are - cheers ! you are going to be a cyanogener shortly :) Try for a nightly build. I must not say they are super stable but you can get a feel of it, assuming you are running a root device.

Comment: My phone is a Motorola Razr D3, no CM available yet.

Comment: I'll award the bounty, and when it work I can mark as an accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the Droid 3 is another one. Mine is Razr D3. But looks like waiting for the CM is the only option for the device volume buttons to work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon) supports such a feature. It is the official Android version of the world-famous [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/). You can change the volume of what you are listening with it while your phone screen is locked. It is available for free on the Google Play Store. VLC is still in Beta status however it is quite stable and it works well.

It should be noted that VLC is only available for devices with a ARMv7 hardware architecture. And it is the case of the Motorola RAZR D3. ;-)

Comment: Not working here. Not sure if I was clear, but with "screen locked" I mean locked and turned off. In the lock scree, with the screen on, the players work fine.

Comment: @TomBrito : This is what I understood. I have got a Nexus 4 and volume control of VLC works fine with the screen locked *AND* turned off.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wearing a headset when listening to your podcasts (which I assume), and those are wired and provide a physical button for play/pause, there might be an additional option using physical controls:

The playstore offers a bunch of [headset control apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=headset+control&c=apps) -- some of them manufacturer specific, others explicitly manufacturer independent (in praxis, both mostly work manufacturer independently -- it just might take you a while to find the one working best with your headset). Those utilize the single button most headsets offer to perform different tasks. For volume control, with most of them long-pressing the button increases volume, while a short press followed by a long one decreases volume (in both cases, until either you let go of the button or the volume reaches the end of its scale, whatever happens first).

I personally tried two of them: first I used [JAYS Headset Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.jays.headsetcontrol), which worked fine for increasing, but failed in 90% for decreasing volume -- which I address to the fact that I don't have a Jays headset. So having a Philips headset, I tried [Philips Headset](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.philips.cl.headset) next, and as expected it worked perfectly.

[image: Jays Headset Control] [image: HeadsetButton Controler] [image: Philips Headset]
<sup>[JAYS Headset Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.jays.headsetcontrol), the rather device independent [HeadsetButton Controler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kober.headset), and [Philips Headset](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.philips.cl.headset) (Source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

As you can see by these example screenshots, "command sequences" seem to be almost standardized (for combinations up to 3 presses, that is -- the "quadruple click" seems to be an added speciality of *HeadsetButton Controller*). So if you want/have to switch at a later time, you do not even have to change your customs regarding this :)

Comment: If you can use Bluetooth headsets which support [HSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Audio.2FVideo_Remote_Control_Profile_.28AVRCP.29) profile like [Jabra BT3030](http://www.amazon.com/cell-phones-accessories/dp/B000XT3L7W) you can control the volume without even touching the phone.

Comment: Really sad, the Sony phones that I like don't have any button, but will search for new ones. I consider a huge fail of the system not being able to handle the device own volume buttons with screen locked. Even my old Sony Ericsson w300 would handle the volume fine. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: I really wonder why it shouldn't work via the hardware volume buttons anyway. It did on all of my devices I ever had (including a *Motorola Milestone 2*, so it's not just Motorola per se). Admitted, none of my *phones* run JB, as you can see in my profile...